# AbotX Licence File in a Web (MVC) App Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the AbotX Web Crawler in a project and have recently purchased the 'Professional' licence.

The licence file has the extension `.lic` and according to documentation, should be placed in the same folder as `AbotX.dll`.

I have the following folder setup on my MVC5 web project:

```
/...
/bin/AbotX.dll
/bin/AbotX.lic
/bin/MyProject.dll
/bin/...etc
/Views/...
/Controllers/...
/Models/...
```

...and so on...standard MVC project set up.

The only issue is, my licence file doesn't seem to be recognised at runtime. Specifically, I am using the `ParallelCrawlerEngine` but even though my licence permits it, I can't change the `MaxConcurrentSiteCrawls` to be above `3`:

```
var my_config = new CrawlConfigurationX
{
    MaxConcurrentSiteCrawls = 5,
    SitesToCrawlBatchSizePerRequest = 25,
    MinSiteToCrawlRequestDelayInSecs = 15,
    IsJavascriptRenderingEnabled = false,
    JavascriptRenderingWaitTimeInMilliseconds = 3500,
    MaxPagesToCrawl = 0,
    MaxPagesToCrawlPerDomain = 10000
};
```

I've spoken with the author Steven who has been really helpful and has even put together a Console app proving my licence file is correct and allows > 3 concurrent crawls.

The only issue is that the Console App is structurally different to my web app so has anyone ever integrated the AbotX licence file into an MVC app? Is there anything specific I need to do to get this up and running?

I've tried putting the `lic` file in every folder and cleared my local IIS Temporary folders to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a configurable path I made the search for the license a little more universal. Update to the latest AbotX version 1.1.67 to try it out. I tested this locally with a console app and a Asp.net MVC web app running on IIS express. I assume this will work on Azure as well but please let me know if that is not true.

It now uses the following to search for the license...

```
var licFile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\AbotX.lic";
```

Comment: Hi Steven, that's great. Thank you very much for this. I will have a look at this next week

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I've recreated your environment and used trail version of AbotX Web Crawler to check licence issue. Here is what I've deducted. Based on your comments and with the help of dotPeek :) I come to conclusion that AbotX looks for current directory to locate a licence file. In case of a console app it will be a bin folder (where the exe file is located). However, a web app is executed with the help of IIS so the current directory will be the main folder of a IIS/IIS Express. In my case that was: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express. You can check your current directory during runtime using this command:

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
```

I didn't find any documentation regarding manual setting of license file path so temporary solution would be to manually cope licence file to current IIS directory. I've checked it myslef and it works like a charm with MaxConcurrentSiteCrawls > 3 :)

Comment: thank you. I will look into that. My next question though is - how would I translate this to an Azure Web App environment? :/

Comment: the simplest solution would be to ask owner of the AbotX for the way to manually/by config set a path to licence file in case it cannot be placed in the same folder as a dll. That should be pretty straight forward to implement for him.

Comment: Then just place licence file inside App_Data folder and provide file path to AbotX like this: Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/AbotX.lic"); If App_Data folder is not empty it will be automatically published to Azure :)